# io.popen():lines() ignores first non-empty line

Tags: lua, popen

I have a shell script that has an output like this:

```
1
Space Cruise (Title)
Ben Prunty Music
FTL
46.4
```

Now I want to map the lines to an array like this:

```
mymplayer = { track="", title="", artist="", album="", time="" }
```

So I'm using io.popen() like this (for testing purposes):

```
function get_data()
    local fh = io.popen("bin/mplayerout.sh")
    for l in fh:lines() do print(l) end
end
```

The problem is that this has the following output:

```
Space Cruise (Title)
Ben Prunty Music
FTL
46.4
```

Now, if I make my script's output start with a newline, the output is like this:

```
<empty line>
Space Cruise (Title)
Ben Prunty Music
FTL
46.4
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I found the issue. When doing the same in Python, I got the first line - but as 3281 null bytes (`'\x00'`) followed by `'\x02\n'`.

Looks like the problem is in the script...

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the first line of output from `mplayerout.sh` ends in a carriage return (`"\r"`) while the others end in newlines (`"\n"` or `"\r\n"`.)

Then the initial `"1"` would still be in the output, but the `"\r"` will cause the terminal to overwrite it with the following characters.

You can see this by using `print(string.format("%q", l))`.  If there is a `"\r"` embedded in the first line, the output will be:

```
"1\rSpace Cruise (Title)"
"Ben Prunty Music"
"FTL"
"46.4"
```